# opsworks: 'update custom cookbooks' from command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-cli, aws-opsworks

Is there a way to [update custom cookbooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-enable-update.html) from the command line on an opsworks instance?

I don't see a way to do it with the [AWS OpsWorks Agent CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/agent.html) or with the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

The only way I am able to do it is through the console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be possible using the create-deployment command.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/create-deployment.html

Note: Haven't done this myself, currently working on it though!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it is the correct answer. When sending this command I use ` --command "{\"Name\":\"update_custom_cookbooks\"}"` and works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure .aws/config (default) is set
2. `aws opsworks --region us-east-1 create-deployment --stack-id $STACK_ID --app-id $APP_ID --command "{\"Name\":\"update_custom_cookbooks\"}"`

   or

   `aws opsworks --region us-east-1 create-deployment --stack-id $STACK_ID --app-id $APP_ID --command "{\"Name\":\"deploy\"}"`

   Replace `$STACK_ID` and `$APP_ID` and `--region` with respective to your application.

Answer (score 1):

I find that `--app-id` isn't strictly necessary to create a deployment, and adding a wait is helpful:

```
aws opsworks wait deployment-successful --deployment-id $(
  aws opsworks create-deployment \
    --output text \
    --stack-id $STACK_ID \
    --command "{\"Name\":\"update_custom_cookbooks\"}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

OpsWorks only has the config for where to get your cookbooks from, as your link clearly states. To update the content, you do it yourself. Either update the git repo, or upload a new ZIP bundle to whichever HTTP server you are using (usually S3).

Comment: Yes, im trying to automate it so i do a berks package and push that to s3 but ten i want to automate updating the instance

Comment: You can use the OpsWorks CLI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/cli-examples-execute-recipe.html

Comment: I've looked at that but i only see an option to execute a recipe, not to update custom cookbooks.